# Java bubble sorter needs to count swaps and comparisons

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I am fairly new to Java. I am creating sorting algorithms on an int array such that each method keeps a count of the number of swaps and comparisons they make. I am having trouble with it displaying the Original Order, Sorted Order, Swaps and Comparisons. Not sure what I have to do to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class IntBubbleSorter {

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array)
    {
        int lastPos;
        int index;
        int temp;
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;

        for (lastPos = array.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--)
          {
            for (index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++)
            {
                count2++;

                if (array[index] > array[index + 1])
                {
                    count++;
                    temp = array[index];
                    array[index] = array[index + 1];
                    array[index + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
          }
        System.out.print("\n Swaps:" + count);

        System.out.print("\n Comparisons:" + count2);
    }
}


public class SortingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] values = { 1,53,86,21,49,32,90,65,33,11,34,68,54,32,78,80,35,22,96,59,265,44324,123,3123,25435};

        System.out.println("Original Order: ");
        for (int element : values) 
            System.out.print(element + " ");

        IntBubbleSorter.bubbleSort(values);

        System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
        for (int element : values) 
            System.out.print(element + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

//This is what it is outputting

```
Original Order: 
1 53 86 21 49 32 90 65 33 11 34 68 54 32 78 80 35 22 96 59 265 44324 123 3123 25435 
 Swaps:80
 Comparisons:300
Sorted order: 
1 11 21 22 32 32 33 34 35 49 53 54 59 65 68 78 80 86 90 96 123 265 3123 25435 44324
```

Comment: Why do you think this isn't correct?

Comment: The main method is getting the original order but then going to the bubble sorter and getting the swaps and comparisons then back to the main method to get the sort, which isn't the order I wanted but anything I try doesn't work. I am going to create more sorting methods that use the same main method and I think its going to get very messy and confusing. Should I have some sort of "Get" method to get the Swaps and comparisons?

Comment: That seems reasonable enough. You might consider creating some sort of abstract base class to implement the comparison and swap functions, then your various sort implementations can inherit the common functionality. I believe [Sedgewick](http://www.informit.com/store/algorithms-in-java-parts-1-4-9780201361209) took that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your comment you could make your counting variables static and put your output in the main method like so:

```
public class IntBubbleSorter {

    public static int count = 0;

    public static int count2 = 0;

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array)
    {
        int lastPos;
        int index;
        int temp;
        count = 0;
        count2 = 0;

        for (lastPos = array.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--)
          {
            for (index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++)
            {
                count2++;

                if (array[index] > array[index + 1])
                {
                    count++;
                    temp = array[index];
                    array[index] = array[index + 1];
                    array[index + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
          }
    }
}


public class SortingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] values = { 1,53,86,21,49,32,90,65,33,11,34,68,54,32,78,80,35,22,96,59,265,44324,123,3123,25435};

        System.out.println("Original Order: ");
        for (int element : values) 
            System.out.print(element + " ");

        IntBubbleSorter.bubbleSort(values);

        System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
        for (int element : values) 
            System.out.print(element + " ");

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("\n Swaps:" + IntBubbleSorter.count);

        System.out.print("\n Comparisons:" + IntBubbleSorter.count2);
    }
}
```

But I should mention that `static` should be used with care.

Comment: I have tried this but int the main you have System.out.print("\n Swaps:" + count); and System.out.print("\n Comparisons:" + count2); I get an error for "count" and "count2". It wants me to create a local variable or field for them.

Comment: @ducatigirl74 My bad, I was so eager to answer that I missed that your code example contained two different classes. Should work now.

Comment: That looked like it would have worked but I am still getting error. "Change visibility of count (or count 2) to package or create getter and setter for them.

Comment: @ducatigirl74 That is strange, what IDE are you using? However, the problem can be solved if you change the `public static int` to `static int`.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Neon on a Mac. I have changed the JRE from 8 to 7 because they both give different errors at times. Where am I taking out the "public static int" exactly? I will display the code again.

Comment: Ayutac I got it to work! I see whereI had the "private static int" instead of making it public which solved it! THANK YOU!!!!! I just can't thank you enough!

Comment: @ducatigirl74 No problem. If you want to do me a favor, please mark my answer as accepted, i.e. click  check mark below my answer score ;-)